# Vuetify Offline Docs

Tags: vue.js, documentation, offline, vuetify.js, offline-browsing

I have started using Vuetify to add ui-components and use pre-defined layouts. The problem is that I have to look into online-docs every now and then, and requires me to be connected to internet perpetually.

Is there a way to get offline docs for Vuetify? Like an html built with doxygen/javadocs, or a CHM? PDF? LaTEX? Anything really helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Update

`git clone https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com.git` has become a private project. The docs are now in the `packages/docs/` directory. Instructions have been updated.

---

You can download the project from the vuetifyjs site repo, install and run locally.

git repo: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify

The instructions (for vue-cli-2 based project):

```sh
    cd /tmp/
    git clone https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify.git
    cd vuetify/packages/docs
    yarn

    # option 1 - build and serve
    yarn build
    yarn start

    # option 2 - run dev instance
    yarn dev
```

Comment: These pages have been 404'd, could you please update the links.

Comment: Not familiar with vuejs or the project in general, that's why I'm leaving a comment (someone else can double-check if it's the right project or not). Found the website, the website links to https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify -- dunno if that's the right link though

Comment: I am looking for pdf doc for vuejs, the problem with the local node server is that, though they can be viewed, they can't be searched like regular pdf.

Comment: If you run into this error: `yarn run build exited 127 in 'vuetify'` just use the node version **12.16.2** as mentioned here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11169. 
How to set the version -> follow this: https://michael-kuehnel.de/node.js/2015/09/08/using-vm-to-switch-node-versions.html

Answer (score 7):

See [the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/contributing#yarn) on how to run the docs.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify.git
cd vuetify
yarn
yarn build
yarn dev docs
```

Then head over to http://localhost:8095/en/getting-started/quick-start

Comment: They changed the build process over time and this worked for me - state 09/21/2020

Answer (score 3):

```
git clone https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify.git
yarn
yarn build
yarn start
http://localhost:8095
```

Comment: Hi Alec, please could you add a description to go with your terminal snippet.

Answer (score 0):

1. download zip from https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify
2. extract it to any place like i put it in d:\xampp\htdcos\vuetify-master
3. than open command prompt (cmd) and type this path d:\xampp\htdcos\vuetify-master
4. run this command yarn here D:\xampp\htdocs\vuetify-master>yarn
5. than run yarn build here D:\xampp\htdocs\vuetify-master>yarn build
6. than yarn start here D:\xampp\htdocs\vuetify-master>yarn start
7. it will start vuetify local docs at 0.0.0.0:8095
8. now open browser and type http://localhost:8095 and enjoy

node module is required 
also install yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable before running yarn commands and make sure check yarn version in cmd via yarn -v

Answer (score 0):

The **Vuetify** website allows you to view it offline there by typing its website and pressing enter when not connected to the internet. It works and I do that all the time.