# Try to get the vuetify docs run local

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, yarnpkg

I try to make the vuetify docs available on my mac local.

I followed the steps in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293026/15037167

```
cd /tmp/
git clone https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify.git
cd vuetify/packages/docs
yarn

# option 1 - build and serve
yarn build
yarn start

# option 2 - run dev instance
yarn dev
```

Every thing works until the step "type: yarn dev".

```
error: Cannot find module '/vue/vuetify/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

I already had problems with the step "type yarn" but I solved this with downgrading node like mentioned in the linked post.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you have to install vuetify. (Confuse why I need to install vuetify inside vuetify's source code).

Work around:

```sh
yarn add @nuxtjs/vuetify -D
# or
npm install @nuxtjs/vuetify -D
```

Comment: I tried to use ``yarn add`` but not working at all. In contrast,``npm install`` works fine.

Comment: Fix: use this ``npm install vuetify -D``